# How to parse inner content of description of rss feed MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rss

I am exploring that how to parse RSS feed using MVC, actually while parsing RSS description part has images/videos, then I don't know how to parse them from description. I am only able to parse the description part of RSS feed.

If I want to show these images or videos in other place then how can I do it. Please help me to overcome this problem.

here is my code which I have used to display information other then media (I searched on web but did not find anything useful):

```
String RssFeedUrl = "RSSFeedURL HERE";

List<Feed> feeds = new List<Feed>();
try
{
  XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
  xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
  var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
      select new
      {
    title = x.Element("title").Value,
        link = x.Element("link").Value,
        pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
        description = x.Element("description").Value
      });
  if (items != null)
  {
    foreach (var i in items)
    {
      Feed f = new Feed
          {
        Title = i.title,
            Link = i.link,
            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
            Description = i.description
          };

          feeds.Add(f);
    }
  }

  return View(feeds);
```

Comment: You need to include the code that you've got so far so we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

For RSS feeds you should use the `SyndicationFeed` class.

This link gives you an idea http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steveres/archive/2008/01/20/using-syndicationfeed-to-displaying-photos-from-spaces-live-com.aspx

you can loop through each item and get attributes for each

```
string url = "http://www.SomeSite.com/rss‎";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach (var feedItem in feed.Items)
{
.... blah
}
```

Im not sure what you mean by images and videos,if you update your question with an example of the feed you're parsing then I'll update my answer to suit.

Comment: I have tried this code but its not giving the media files from description part of rss.

Comment: Update your question with some of the RSS feed that includes the description and media files